# Radio form data

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, onsubmit

I'm trying to figure out how to check if an option in a radio form is selected.

```
<body>
<form id="office">
<label id="ques1"> question 1</label><br/>
    <div class="q1 wrong q1a1"><input type="radio" name="question1"      value="q1a1" /> Answer1 <br/></div>
    <div class="q1 wrong q1a2"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a2" /> Answer2 <br/></div>
    <div class="q1 wrong q1a3"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a3" /> Answer3 <br/></div>
    <div class="q1 right q1a4"><input type="radio" name="question1" value="q1a4" /> Answer4 <br/></div>

        <br/><br/>

 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submitAnswers" value="Submit Your   Answers" onclick="checkFunction()" />


</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
if (document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=question1]').checked == true) { console.log('checked');
} else {
console.log('not checked');
}
};
};
</script>
</body>
```

This answers seems to work on one question, with a specific answer, but i don't know how to determine which answer will be the one set as 'checked' in each question (I have 10 questions)

Any ideas?

I would prefer a solution that doesn't include JQuery, since I study HTML and JavaScript.

Thanks!!

Comment: *"This answers seems to work on one question, with a specific answer"* - The selector `'input[type=radio][name=question1]'` matches all four of your radio buttons, but because you have used `querySelector()` rather than `querySelectorAll()` you only actually select the first one.

Comment: @nnnnnn I see. So how I can determine a different answer for each question that will get the 'checked' indicator? Thanks!

Comment: `onclick="checkFunction()"` where the `checkFunction`

Comment: @Ramanlfc doesnt 'document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {' replace it?. if not, i will add 'function checkFunction() {'